# Why do I seem to get TEXTMETRIC structure's tmHeight member's size in pixel, but not in logical units?

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

Windows GDI documentation clearly states that

> All sizes are specified in logical units; that is, they depend on the current mapping mode of the display context.

When I do such thing inside WndProc:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
TEXTMETRIC textmetric;
GetTextMetrics(hdc, &textmetric);
```

tmHeight is equal to 16 points, which is

```
16 * GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY) / 72
```

pixels. Of course, if I understand this article correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels

But when I create static edit control with some text and specify control height to be 16 pixel it strangely matches text font height. 
[image]

My question is why does this font actually fit in 16 pixels when it should have a size of 16 * 96 / 72 pixels?

Comment: For `MM_TEXT` maping _each logical unit is mapped to one device pixel_. Have you tried with other mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [TEXTMETRICA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-textmetrica) doc:

> The TEXTMETRIC structure contains basic information about a physical
>   font. All sizes are specified in logical units.

So `tmHeight` is in logical units. You don't have to use the following code to get the height of a character.

`lfHeight = -MulDiv(PointSize, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72);`

And the default mapping mode of the system is [MM_TEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/mapping-modes-and-translations).

> Each unit in page space is mapped to one pixel; that is, no scaling is
>   performed at all. When no translation is in effect (this is the
>   default), page space in the MM_TEXT mapping mode is equivalent to
>   physical device space. The value of x increases from left to right.
>   The value of y increases from top to bottom.

So through mapping transformation, the pixel height of the character is equal to the height of the static control.